# JPEG-compressed .EPS causes .PDF size to skyrocket when used with dvipdfmx

Tags: graphics, eps, dvipdfmx, jpeg

I'm about to submit an article to an IEEE journal. They want biographies with photographs, and have specifically instructed that the photograph should be in EPS or PDF format. I have a photograph in JPEG format. However, ordinary LaTeX (not PDFLaTeX) does not support JPEG files. So, I had to convert the JPEG to EPS according to the instructions on this question: [TO convert .jpg to .eps format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350246/to-convert-jpg-to-eps-format)

I did a pretty good job at it according to the file sizes. The original JPEG was 101732 bytes but the EPS is 157689 bytes. Not a huge increase in size.

However, when I use `dvipdfmx`, the size of the resulting .PDF file is 1653748 bytes! Over ten times the EPS size. I have verified that the cause of the skyrocketing .PDF file size is actually the photograph I included. If I don't include the photograph, the size of the .PDF file goes down to one tenth of the large size.

Is there any way I can create a PDF file with JPEG-compressed photographs using `dvipdfmx`? I tried including the JPEG file directly, but LaTeX doesn't support the graphics file format and is unable to determine the bounding box. Also, do keep in mind that the IEEE instructions specifically asked for photographs in EPS or PDF format.

The only solution I see now is to use a lower-resolution photograph in the pre-submission and reviewing stage to keep the file size down, and if the article is accepted, send the IEEE journal editors what they want: the EPS file that causes the PDF size to skyrocket. But it would be nice to somehow figure out a way to include JPEG-compressed photographs.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the jpg directly to pdf?

Comment: I tested that now. With dvipdfmx, it did not help (regular latex doesn't support PDF graphics), but if I used it with pdflatex, I actually managed to reduce the file size to 400K bytes. I initially thought that pdflatex would not work because my other vector graphics are in .eps format, but apparently it just caused pdflatex to convert the graphics from .eps to .pdf.